# exiting current terminal in a script

Tags: ubuntu, shell, bash-alias

I have made alias for running certain program and i have put it in `.bashrc` file.
I want to close current terminal
inside the script. I've tried this but it is not working.

```
alias mp='java -jar myprogram.jar & && kill $(echo $$)'
```

it seems that it can't kill itself.
working os is ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
alias mp='java -jar myprogram.jar & && kill -SIGHUP $(echo $$)'
```

I actually didn't try your whole command, but adding `-SIGHUP` to the kill command did close my terminal.

From [the Wikipedia page on Unix signals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal):

> The SIGHUP signal is sent to a process when its controlling terminal
>   is closed. It was originally designed to notify the process of a
>   serial line drop (a hangup). In modern systems, this signal usually
>   means that the controlling pseudo or virtual terminal has been
>   closed.[3] Many daemons will reload their configuration files and
>   reopen their logfiles instead of exiting when receiving this
>   signal.[4] nohup is a command to make a command ignore the signal.